# How can I get images to display in proportion to the size of the window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, xaml

[image]

I have a 333x 344 pixel image that I am displaying in WPF and it always displays the same size irrespective of the size of the window.
Image is inside a dockpanel but changing dockpanel to grid didn't help.

How can I get it in proportion to the size of the window?

```
<Window>
<ScrollViewer>
<ItemSontrol>
<Usercontrol>
<Grid>
<DockPanel>
<Image/>
</DockPanel>
</Grid>
</Usercontrol>
</ItemSontrol>
</ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

or

```
<ItemSontrol>
<Usercontrol>
<Grid>
<Grid>
<Image/>
</Grid>
</Grid>
</Usercontrol>
</ItemSontrol>
```

Edit: Below didn't fix the size.
DockPanel/Grid surrounding the image can be replaced with any other layout panels. Others cannot be changed.

```
img.Stretch = Stretch.None
```

Comment: Can you please post the XAML code of your window?

Comment: remove the scrollview

Comment: @thumbmunkeys Can't do that. There is some other grid which is too big for the window and needs a scrollviewer.

Answer (score 1):

Embed the image in a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and make sure its parent will restrict its size to the respective window (like a `Grid`)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width, height, VerticalAligment and HorizontalAlignment properties from the image in the xaml code.

Answer (score 0):

The default [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `ItemsControl` is a `StackPanel`, which restricts the space used by items in the direction of the "stack" (vertical by default). If you set the `Stretch` to `Fill` you would probably see it stretch to fill the horizontal space. A solution would be to change the panel template to a grid:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate>

    <UserControl>
        ...
    </UserControl>
</ItemsControl>
```

But in this case it wouldn't make sense to use an `ItemsControl` at all because you are filling the whole area with a single item. The `UserControl` is now the first item in the items collection and any additional items will be stacked on top it in a grid (unless you add row/column definitions to the panel template grid and define `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` on the items). Are you trying to create a background or container for list items? In that case you should probably be defining the `ItemsControl`'s `ControlTemplate` instead.